# in node.js using socket.io, how to add to socket listener dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, socket.io

if have standard `socket.io` setup:

```
var app = require('http').createServer().listen(80,'127.0.5.12'),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

session = require('./local_modules/session.js');

// creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without any AJAX request
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

  // session, login, logout
  socket.on( 'session', session.session.bind(socket) );
  socket.on( 'login', session.login.bind(socket) );
  socket.on( 'logout', session.logout.bind(socket) );

  // what to add new listener here!
});
```

later in the program, once it knows what it wants to do, it wishes to add new functionality to the socket listener.  for example, in the middle of 'session' might wish to add 'something-new':

```
exports.session = function( sid) {
  var socket = this;
  ...
  // everything cool, now want to add 'something-now' to socket
  // do I simply - will something simple as this work?
  socket.on( 'something-new', session.something_new.bind(socket) );
}

exports.something_new = function( arg ) {
}
```

is this correct - it just seems wrong?

Comment: It really isn't clear what you want your program to do or how it's going wrong.

Comment: You can pass the `socket` around in function parameters, or store them off in an object (maybe keyed by the user's session ID, or something like that).

Comment: @ebohlman nothing wrong.  right now listens for 'session', 'login', and 'logout'.  want to extend functionality to listen for 'something-new' calling `whatever.func`.  does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to call 'whatever.func()' on the socket event 'something-new'

```
socket.on('something-new', whatever.func(data) );
```

or

```
socket.on('something-new', function(data){
  whatever.func(data);
  whatelse.func(data.someproperty);
});
```

should work, while 'data' is the first argument passed, when emitting 'something-new'.

Comment: think I'm being inordinately dense today.  changed by question just to make sure you answered it, if you don't mind.